# I bought a car from a small dealership without knowing the dealer didnt have the title

Tags: car, auto-loan

Ok i bought a car from a small dealership (mom and pop style) first time ever doing this. i was told that i would be receiving my tags via mail, ok no problem there. Several weeks passed still no plates so i decided to call the manager at the dealership, he then explains to me he hasn't received the title from the wholesaler he bought the car from. This is where i start to worry. So i called my bank who financed the loan they told me that they havent gotten any word on the title either which i reply am i paying for a car i will never receive a title for? Their response was give it a few more weeks and call us back. My question is what can i do about this? what if they never get the title, am i just throwing away money every month? Can I drop the car back off at the dealership and ask the bank to close the loan? im so lost right now. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd take the car back and ask for a refund.

Comment: Please specify the country, it can help getting good answers.

Comment: If you don't have the title, you didn't _buy_ the car. It could be simply sloppy delays, or could be a scam (stolen car?)